# Ctrl+Alt+T brings up Trash folder, not a Terminal?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, compiz, command-line

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 - wow it's got fast and responsive! It's a joy to operate!

And until just a few moments ago I was very pleased with everything.

I have installed `gnome-tweak-tool`, `compiz-config-settings-manager`, etc and it has been working fine for the last couple of days.

I decided to try to change my keyboard layout so my <kbd>cmd</kbd> button (the machine is a macBook pro) would act more like it does in OS X - I was able to do this with ease :D

Problem is, somewhere along the way my shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for bringing up a terminal got mixed up - it now somehow brings up my trash folder instead!

I checked my keyboard bindings and it says:

> Open a terminal:   Ctrl+Alt+T

CCSM says the same thing!

gnome-tweak-tool also tells me that this is the shortcut...

I've tried reassigning it everywhere, but it seems it won't work? Is this a bug or am I missing something somewhere? ;)

Is there somewhere a shortcut for opening the trash folder is set? I can't seem to find it - I guess that is what I need to undo?

EDIT: If I hold down just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, I get up the window listing the shortcuts.

There in the top left corner under launcher the last one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> Opens trash! 
So this is what is causing it, but where do I change that setting?

Comment: excellent - just click the tick button next to your answer to close the question.

Comment: Apparently i'm only able to do that after 19 hours? hmm..

Comment: yeah ... stick around ... when you start earning more rep - the answer time will start to reduce and eventually it will be "zero" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it to be compiz doing the things - I did some customization and at first I wanted <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> to bring up my launcher - but setting this in compiz makes <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> bring up trash instead of terminal, I bound my commands otherwise and worked around the issue, but I'll leave this post open for future people with the same issue. Or maybe to get the problem solved, or at least an explanation to why it behaves at it does! 
Compiz seems buggy anyhow - lot of CPU usage etc. so I guess there's a good chance this is some compiz bug too.